# equivalence relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $S$ be the collection of everywhere  defined  differentiable functions.
Define a relation $R$ on $S$ as follows:

*$f$  is related to $g$ if there exist a nonzero $k$ such that $f'(x) =kg'(x)$ for
all $x$.

Prove $R$ is an equivalence relation  on $S$

Comment: What have you tried? Have you attempted to write down what it would mean for $R$ to be reflexive? symmetric? transitive?

Answer (score 1):

To show that $*$ is an equivalence relation, we have to show: 
1) Reflextivity $f * f$, for all $f$.  
2) Symmetry: $f * g \implies g * f$ 
3) Transitivity $f * g$ and $g * h \implies f * h$

1) Reflextivity is trivial. Let $k = 1$.

2) Symmetry. If $f^{\prime}(x) = kg^{\prime}(x)$, divide both sides by $k$.

3) Transitivity. Suppose $f^{\prime}(x) = kg^{\prime}(x)$ and $g^{\prime}(x) = ch^{\prime}(x)$. Then we can substitute: $f^{\prime}(x) = ck h^{\prime}(x)$.